# C++ execute bat/sh file and choose variant from UI

Tags: c++, console, system

Faced a problem during the implementation of the launch of the script under the UI in C++ with SDL2.

The task is that a script is launched by pressing a button in the UI. Further, the option should be selected in the script (entering the number in the console, in the script), but I cannot do this by pressing the button.
The script is run as `system("script.bat")` through a separate thread to avoid blocking the UI.

Further, according to the script's logic, a number should be entered and enter is pressed, but here I don’t know how to do it. Tried `system("echo 1\n")` and `std::cout << "1" << std::endl` doesn't work.
Maybe I should implement this in another way?

Buttons code:

```
    if (ui::Button().text("Start script"))
    {
        m_thread = std::thread([this]() { // in thread to avoid blocking the UI
            system("script.bat");
        });
    }

    if (ui::Button().text("Variant 1"))
    {
        system("echo 1\n");
        std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Each time you call system() you open a new independent console.

Comment: @drescherjm Maybe I should change the implementation way? Can you tell me which way to look?

Comment: Can't you start the script with command line arguments when button #1 is pressed. And when button2 is pressed instead of starting the script and then trying to feed it data later.

Comment: @drescherjm Is there a direction in which to think?